# Java error: The method XXX in the type XXX is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java

There is an error in the method **add** in the following java text:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class test {
    Vector<? extends CellObject> v = new Vector<>();

    class Cell extends CellObject {
        // some definitions here
        public Cell() {
            v.add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Why I can't use bounded wildcard? My problem that at the moment (and in the place) of creating the vector **v** I really don't know future subclass that will be stored in the vector.

I know that in the case

```
    Vector<CellObject> v = new Vector<>();
```

there will be no error, but components of the vector are not of the class CellObject.

Comment: Why do you use the obsolete/legacy `java.util.Vector` collection (not related to the concrete problem)?

Comment: Notice that `<>` expands to `<CellObject>` in both cases. Both vectors have the same type. The only difference is that in first case you are using more generic type on `v`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Vector<? extends CellObject>
```

tells the compiler: this is a Vector, which contains instances of an **unknown** subclass of CellObject (or of CellObject itself). All you can safely assume is that it contains instances of CellObject. But it could be a `Vector<CellObject>`, or a `Vector<SubCellObject>`, or a `Vector<SomeOtherCellObject>`: you just don't know.

So, to guarantee the type-safety of the collection, you can't add anything except null to this vector. You really don't want to add a `SubCellObject` to a `Vector<SomeOtherCellObject>`.

BTW: Vector is obsolete since Java 1.2. We're at Java 8. It's time to move on. And you shouldn't use a raw type to initialize your vaiable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This was easy. But about Vector. I need only unlimit storage, iteration throght collection and quick access to stored objects via links in other stored objects. What is better and more modern to use in Java with the same efficiency?

Comment: ArrayList is the replacement for Vector. Quote from the javadoc of Vector: it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector

Comment: Yes, I know. But from the javadoc:

Comment: "Note that this implementation is not synchronized."

Comment: @ABC and why would you need it synchronized? Even if you do, then you should use `Collectionc.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`

Answer (score 1):

Because the Java compiler doesn't know what actual type to assign to `v`.

If the objects being stored are subclasses of `CellObject`, then they are assignment compatible with `CellObject`, so you should be able just to use `Vector<CellObject>`. That's the whole point of polymorphism. It just means: create a `Vector` in which I can store anything of `CellObject` or below in the type hierarchy.

If using `Vector<? extends CellObject>` in that context were meaningful, it could only mean the same as `Vector<CellObject>`.